# Unable to convert Sentinel-5P NetCDF file to GeoTIFF using xarray python

Tags: python, xarray

I am trying to convert Sentinel-5P NetCDF file (available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dJdhQspdI3p5YyyiBBiNxUPCCOU91QrU/view?usp=sharing) to GeoTIFF using the following code:

```
import xarray

netcdf_fname = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NC Files\CH4_1.nc'

xds = xarray.open_dataset(netcdf_fname, group='PRODUCT')

param = xds.methane_mixing_ratio
param.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="longitude", y_dim="latitude", inplace=True)
param.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)

param.rio.to_raster(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NC Files\ch4_raster.tif')
```

After running the above code I am getting the following error:
`MissingSpatialDimensionError: x dimension (longitude) not found. Data variable: methane_mixing_ratio`

How can I resolve this issue?

The output of variables 'xds' & 'param' is:

```
xds
'''
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                              (scanline: 4173, ground_pixel: 215, time: 1, corner: 4, layer: 12, level: 13)
Coordinates:
  * scanline                             (scanline) float64 0.0 ... 4.172e+03
  * ground_pixel                         (ground_pixel) float64 0.0 ... 214.0
  * time                                 (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-07-06
  * corner                               (corner) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
  * layer                                (layer) float64 0.0 1.0 ... 10.0 11.0
  * level                                (level) float64 0.0 1.0 ... 11.0 12.0
    latitude                             (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
    longitude                            (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
Data variables:
    delta_time                           (time, scanline) datetime64[ns] 2021...
    time_utc                             (time, scanline) object '2021-07-06T...
    qa_value                             (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
    methane_mixing_ratio                 (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
    methane_mixing_ratio_precision       (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
    methane_mixing_ratio_bias_corrected  (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
'''   
    
param
''' 
<xarray.DataArray 'methane_mixing_ratio' (time: 1, scanline: 4173, ground_pixel: 215)>
[897195 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * scanline      (scanline) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 ... 4.171e+03 4.172e+03
  * ground_pixel  (ground_pixel) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 ... 212.0 213.0 214.0
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-07-06
    latitude      (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
    longitude     (time, scanline, ground_pixel) float32 ...
Attributes:
    units:                1e-9
    standard_name:        dry_atmosphere_mole_fraction_of_methane
    long_name:            column averaged dry air mixing ratio of methane
    ancillary_variables:  methane_mixing_ratio_precision column_averaging_ker...
'''
```

Comment: Could you add the output from `xds` and `param` to your question, that would help to understand whats going on.

Comment: Hi @Bert. I have modified the question and added the output of variables 'xds' and 'param'.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `x_dim` and `y_dim` in `param.rio.set_spatial_dims` is done so that rio knows which dimensions to use along the y and x axis (in case they are different from the standard names `"x"` and `"y"`).

You are telling rio that the coordinates on the x-axis can be found in something called `longitude`. But this name does not exist in the dimensions of the variable you are interested in: the `methane_mixing_ratio` variable has a shape of (1, 4173, 215) and its dimensions are `"time"`, `"scanline"` and `"ground_pixel"`. So you can only use those three names to specify the `x_dim` and `y_dim`.

I'm not so familiar with this product, but it seems to me like GeoTiff is perhaps not the best way to store this data, since I'm not sure it's gridded data. If it is, you'd probably have to calculate the latitudes and longitudes yourself first.

Comment: Thanks @Bert for the answer and explanation. In this case/product, latitude and longitude also have shapes as (1, 4173, 215) and values range between (-90 to 90) for latitude & (-180 to 180) for longitude. Here what I want is to convert the selected parameter of this nc file to Geotiff which can then be use for further GIS processing and analysis.

Comment: @Bert is right, the data isn't projected. If you look at the distance between the e.g. longitude samples, I get different values (from -0.04 to 0.04), suggesting that this is swath data that needs to be reprojected.